# How to avoid duplicated records in a multi-thread application?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008-r2

I have multiple threads generating data and store them into DB. The generated data could be duplicated. I don't want duplication in DB. My current solution is to use a lock in the C# code to force the multiple threads write to DB synchronously. i.e. Each thread check if its data already exists in DB and store only the new data. But this seems to hurt the performance. Is there any better solution? Maybe let the database to handle the duplication?

I am using SQL Sever 2008 R2.

Comment: You are not the first to have this problem. See https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql+server+avoid+duplicated+records+ for a wealth of strategies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unique index and constraints for preventing duplicates in database. You can handle exceptions when dublication happens.

Comment: I tried to add unique constraint. But that column has length of 2000, which exceeds the 900 limit of index column.

Comment: You can create unique constraint instead of index. Also you can split your long column to many short-typed columns

Answer (score 1):

If there is a unique key that identifies each row, a unique constraint could be put on the table to prevent duplicity. Its using an index to check uniqueness so it should be efficient.

Also, SQLServer can return an error message to the C# code in the client app to let them know that the contraint has been violated.

EDIT based on additional info:
-- if your unique column is more than 900 bytes, try a trigger based solution or an MD5 (only 64 bytes) of the unique column, and create a unique constraint based on the MD5 column. You could use a computed column to achieve this eg.

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.LookupValues ADD bigColumnhash AS
    HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', bigColumn) PERSISTED;
    GO


    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_LookupValues_bigColumnhash
    on dbo.LookupValues (bigColumnhash) INCLUDE (bigColumn);
    GO
```